# Insert function for bst not working

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

If anyone can help me with the recursion part?
I omitted some part thnking that it was not necessary but after that function didn't work.

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.data=value
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

def insert(Node,value):
    if Node is None:
        Node=node(value)
    else:
        if value<Node.data:
##            if Node.left is None: Node.left=node(value)
##            else: insert(Node.left,value)
            insert(Node.left,value)
        else:
##            if Node.left is None: Node.left=node(value)
##            else: insert(Node.left,value)
            insert(Node.right,value)
```

Comment: 1. I imagine that `insert` is intended to be a method of the `node` `class`. In that case it should be indented. Also, `Node` would become `self.Node` in certain places. 2. What do you mean by 'recursion part'? 3. In general, you should, please, ask specific programming questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: i have defined insert separately

Comment: my specific question is that why do we need to include the commented parts in the insert function to get it working

Comment: what i can think of is that the work done by those lines can be done directly by recursive call to insert function

Comment: I am a newbie here so i may not be asking questions in the right manner , sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you'll need to create new `node` instances for your empty branches.

Let's see what happens with both definitions, printing out the values of the `Node` parameter:

```
def insert(Node, value):
  print(Node)
  if Node is None:
    Node=node(value)
  else:
    if value<Node.data:
      insert(Node.left,value)
    else:
      insert(Node.right,value)
```

On the REPL:

```
In [17]: badTree = node(10)

In [18]: badTree.data
Out[18]: 10

In [20]: badTree.left.data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3cb52def2967> in <module>()
----> 1 badTree.left.data

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

In [21]: badTree.right.data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b6f1267c9d29> in <module>()
----> 1 badTree.right.data

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Let's see what happens if we insert an element to `badTree`:

```
In [22]: insert(badTree, 2)
<__main__.node object at 0x7f706bf34d30>
None

In [23]: badTree.left.data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3cb52def2967> in <module>()
----> 1 badTree.left.data

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

It fails to insert the element, but why? In `badTree`, both `left` and `right` branches are `None` (empty), what means that we need to create new trees there as we won't be able to recursively add new values, as we lose the reference to the main `Node`. This is, if we call `insert(Node.left, value)` before assigning a new object to `Node.left`, it will be equivalent to call `insert(None, value)` (this the value `None`, you can see it when we called `insert` on `badTree`), which will call recursively to `insert` and execute `None = node(value)` which will do nothing.

What happens if we use this definition instead:

```
def insert(Node, value):
  print(Node)
  if Node is None:
    Node = node(value)
  else:
    if value < Node.data:
      if Node.left is None:
        Node.left = node(value)
      else:
        insert(Node.left, value)
    else:
      if Node.right is None:
        Node.right = node(value)
      else:
        insert(Node.right, value)
```

On the REPL:

```
In [25]: newTree = node(4)

In [26]: insert(newTree, 10)
<__main__.node object at 0x7f706bf30668>

In [27]: insert(newTree, 12)
<__main__.node object at 0x7f706bf30668>
<__main__.node object at 0x7f706bf30a58>
```

Now see that it doesn't fail anymore, as we are keeping track of the memory addresses in the tree nodes and thus we can reference those objects (trees) which will let us do the insertions in-place.